# Match hyphen/dash next to a Certain Letters

Tags: regex, text-processing

Input file:

```
>AMSF107-09|Perciformes|COI-5P|GU661092
TAGTA-
>AMSF114-09|Perciformes|COI-5P|GU661101
C-ACGC
>ANGBF3683-12|Haemulon_sp._B_JJT-2012|COI-5P|JQ741244
-GCAGTT-CA-
```

I want to replace the hyphens in `TAGTA-`, `C-ACGC`, and `-GCAGTT-CA-` with `N`'s but leave the headers (the lines that start with `>`) intact. I'm looking for a regex that will match a hyphen next to an `A`,`C`,`G`, or `T` but exclude matches that begin with the `>` character.

Desired output

```
>AMSF107-09|Perciformes|COI-5P|GU661092
TAGTAN
>AMSF114-09|Perciformes|COI-5P|GU661101
CNACGC
>ANGBF3683-12|Haemulon_sp._B_JJT-2012|COI-5P|JQ741244
NGCAGTTNCAN
```

EDIT:
I know the very basics in regex. So far I've tried `(ACGT)?\-(ACGT)?` but that matches every hyphen.

Comment: Right, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I only know the very basics of regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches a hyphen preceded by `A`, `C`, `G` or `T`: `(?<=[ACGT])-`

Comment: that's close but that also matches the T in the 3rd header. `>ANGBF3683-12|Haemulon_sp._B_JJT-2012|COI-5P|JQ741244`

Comment: What is the language that you're writting in? You can add a simple method that filters the lines

Comment: I'm editing a text file in Sublime using the Find & Replace function. I'm putting the regex in the Find section and `N` in the replace section.

Comment: Ahh ok... So there's a problem, because positive lookbehinds must be fixed length and this means that you can't filter the lines and then find that hyphen in one regex. You can write a simple script for example in python that can accomplish this though.

Answer (score 1):

So this doesn't exactly find just the hyphens, but it will find any combination `A`, `C`, `G`, `T` including a `-`.  Here is the `regex`:

```
(?=[ACGT-]+$)(?=(?:[^-]*[-])+).*
```

You may have to `split` this match of the `string` off and save it to a temporary variable where you then do a `.replace('-', 'N');` and concatenate it back on to the end of your data string.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hold on, it is not quite right.  I thought I tested it but it still has a bug. I'll see if I can fix it, but its close! The problem is that as long as any of your given characters are already in existence in the string, you can then put in any character or number. I'll keep trying to work on it.

Comment: @cooldood3490 accidentally pasted wrong `regex`, it is updated now.

Comment: I appreciate your help